# Matching two dataframes according to rowname and adding NA

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I have 3 dataframes with uneven values for a variable over time as:

The data frames for every observation only contains the variable for which there is a value.

dataframe_a

```
  time_1
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
```

dataframe_b

```
   time_2
a    1
c    3
d    4
e    2
```

dataframe_c

```
 time_3
a    1
b    3
d    4
e    2
```

and want a data frame such as:

```
  time_1 time_2 time_3
a    1      1       1
b    3     NA       3
c    4      3       NA
d    2      4       4
e    NA     2       2
```

I want to match according to rowname and add a missing value if there's no value at that observation
When a variable is introduced on dataframe/observation 3 there should be a NA for observation 1 and 2

rbind, merge, rbind.fill, etc. is not helping me

Thank you
Hopefully this is not a common question

Comment: What have you tried exactly, since you say those functions haven't worked? It seems like a simple couple of left-joins

Comment: How does observation `b` gets a `3` for time_1? The same to `c` and `d` getting `4` and `2` for variable `time_1`? This is not a merge or combine problem unless those are a typo.

Comment: You are right those are typos. The idea is that I have not a value for every variable in every observation but a dataframe for every observation containing only the values for observed varibales. So that's where the mismatch is comming from. The provided solution with reduce fulljoin are working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option with `reduce` and `full_join` after placing the datasets in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
list(a, b, c) %>%
      reduce(full_join, by = "id")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `full_join` function from `dplyr` package can help you:

```
a <- data.frame(id = c("a","b","c","d"),time_1 = 1:4)
b <- data.frame(id = c("a","c","d","e"),time_2 = c(1,3,4,2))
c <- data.frame(id = c("a","b","d","e"),time_3 = c(1,3,4,2))

require(dplyr)
d <- full_join(a,b,by = "id")
full_join(d,c)
```